# Adding a Printer in Windows 8

Tags: printing, windows-8, installation

I am trying to Add a Printer using a custom Port Monitor (PM) to the V3 PScript5 driver, but am having all sorts of issues. I am aware that PM's are not recommended for Windows 8 and will not work against the V4 drivers, but I need it to work on both W7 and W8. Additionally I have not been able to find out what alternatives are available for the PM so have no idea if they are supported on W7. My INF file is based on the sample INF provided by GhostScript and the associated catalog is signed using a valid signing certificate that I use to sign the USB driver my company developed.

Here is the info from the signing certificate:

```
Issued to: Vanguard Graphics International, LLC
Issued by: DigiCert SHA2 Assured ID Code Signing CA
Expires:   Wed Jan 03 13:00:00 2018
SHA1 hash: 48DD5D40AF53A295F494305935791F216E31A5AB
```

Here is the INF file.

;----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
Provider=Xitron LLC
ClassGUID={4D36E979-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
Class=Printer
CatalogFile=XiPrinter.cat
DriverVer=05/07/2015,1.0.0.2

[Manufacturer]
"XiPrinter"=XiPrinter,ntamd64

[XiPrinter]
"XiPrinter"=Install_XiPrinter,Xitron_XiPrinter_1001

[XiPrinter.ntamd64]
"XiPrinter"=Install_XiPrinter,Xitron_XiPrinter_1001

[Install_XiPrinter]
CopyFiles=@XiPrinter.ppd
DataSection=PSCRIPT_DATA
Include=NTPRINT.INF
Needs=PSCRIPT.OEM

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir=66000

[SourceDisksNames]
1=%Disk1%,,,""

[SourceDisksFiles]
XiPrinter.ppd=1

[Strings]
Disk1="XiPrinter Setup Disk 1"
```

; -------------------------------------------------------------------------

I have a folder containing:
    xiprinter.inf
    xiprinter.cat
    xiprinter.ppd

My Port Monitor is already installed and registered with the system. All I need to do is hook the printer up to it and I should be good to go. I have had all sorts of different results from attempts to install the printer. The current one is either 'Operation could not be completed - error 0x00000002' or 'Printer Driver Not installed. This operation is not supported.'

I can post output from ProcMon if that is any help.

As far as I can tell all the files the INF file needs are either next to it, or referenced via the NTPRINT.INF file referenced in my INF file so they should all be present.

Using procmon to monitor the relevant processes (ntprint.exe and spoolsv.exe), I can see them doing a lot of references to my files. It does appear to copy the files to the FileRepository, but it then fails to copy the files into the System32\Spool\drivers\x64 folder so the installation process fails, but I have no ideas as to why the installation should fail.
I am running this as a user with Admin rights.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Peter Young.